# Update Data Records on MySQL using user input

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Ok I have this issue. I need to update a record on my DB but I am having trouble because of my SQL syntax. By pressing the "Update Name" button, 2 messages pop up and the user selects the former name and the new name for the Table. But the statement is never executed and the names wont change. My main goal is to "resolve" the id from the 1st statement to a variable

```
String name_1 = "SELECT id FROM consoles WHERE name LIKE ? ";
```

and add it here

```
String name = "UPDATE consoles SET name = ? WHERE id = ?";
```

Is it possible to resolve to a variable the id I get from my 1st statement?

```
try
{
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1?user=me&password=12345");
    String name_1 = "SELECT id FROM consoles WHERE name LIKE ? ";
    String name = "UPDATE consoles SET name = ? WHERE name LIKE ?";
    PreparedStatement psname = conn.prepareStatement(name);
    PreparedStatement psname_1 = conn.prepareStatement(name_1);
    String strin =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Previous Name : ");
    String strout = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"New Name : "); 
    psname.setString(1,strin);
    psname.setString(2,"%" +strout+ "%");
    psname_1.setString(1,"%"+strin+"%");
    psname.executeUpdate();
    Statement stmtname = conn.createStatement();
    // show the updated table
    ResultSet rsname = stmtname.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM consoles INNER JOIN hardware ON consoles.id=hardware.id"); 
                     .
                     .
                     .
            ADDING THEM TO A JTABLE
                     .
                     .
                     .
```

Comment: "But the statement is never executed and the names wont change." - Do you get an exception, or have you just checked manually on the SQL server whether the execute has been done, or are you assuming it's not working because the GUI wont update?

Comment: i get no errors, but nothing changes on my DB.....

the 2nd

Comment: Haven't you just switched the logic, because the `String strin` is now the previous name, and is put as the parameter as the new name in the `psname`, and vice versa for the new name?

Shouldn't it be `psname.setString(1, strout);` and `psname.setString(2, "%" + strin + "%")`;

Comment: Ιts one of those times where the you have such an "stupid" error and you search deep deep inside your code and you realise that it is so stupid that you start laughing.....SOLVED!

Comment: Its something like - Oh my Laptop wont start.Why? - 
#Opens_PC,#Checks_Hardware,#Cleans_Discs,#Disconnects_Devices,#Hasnt_plugged_battery

Comment: Posted it as suggested answer, even though it's a simple mistake from your side. Consider marking it as answered to avoid further answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments are switched.

```
psname.setString(2,"%" +strout+ "%");
psname_1.setString(1,"%"+strin+"%");
```

should be

```
psname.setString(2, "%" + strin + "%");
psname_1.setString(1, strout);
```

Comment: I posted an anwser in which you dont use another PreparedStatement but only one. But I will keep yours as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test1?user=me&password=12345");
    String name = "UPDATE consoles SET name = ? WHERE name LIKE ?";
    PreparedStatement psname = conn.prepareStatement(name);
    String strin =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Previous Name : ");
    String strout = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"New Name : "); 
    psname.setString(1,strout);
    psname.setString(2,"%" +strin+ "%");
   psname.executeUpdate();
    Statement stmtname = conn.createStatement();
    // show the updated table
    ResultSet rsname = stmtname.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM consoles INNER JOIN hardware ON consoles.id=hardware.id"); 
                     .
                     .
                     .
            ADDING THEM TO A JTABLE
                     .
                     .
                     .
```